# Automate SNX restart with crontab

Tags: linux, cron, vpn

I am using VPN connection using SSL Network Extender(SNX) to connect to remote server. The connection from the remote server is limited to only 12 hours. After that the connection is being disconnected and have to restart the SNX server again. To overcome those hardship I am trying to automate SNX restart using crontab.

1. I have created one shell script file called `vpn.sh`.

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> snx -d
> sleep 3
> echo 'password' | snx
> ```

2. I have config file call `.snxrc` inside home directory

> ```
> server server.com
> username username
> reauth yes
> ```

3. Inside crontab (`crontab -e`) config I have

`* */12 * * * bash /home/username/vpn.sh > /home/username/cron.log`

It runs every 12 hours. But `snx -d` runs successfully but on reaching `echo 'newpass6' | snx` I am getting this error:

`Failed to init terminal!`

Any body encountered such issues? Please help me. I have been struggling for a week now. Thanks in advance.

I have followed this link to setup [snx](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450229/getting-checkpoint-vpn-ssl-network-extender-working-in-the-command-line)

Comment: Its working fine if I directly execute bash script from the command prompt but the problem above arises if this same script is executed in the `crontab`

Comment: No reason to donwvote, I have similar problems... +1

Comment: alternative for me was to use screen command, which allowed me to run snx as systemd service. Although I had to also use sleep 365d after snx invocation so that screen does not exit immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because snx client cannot start without a terminal. So i put in my script these commands to start snx in a byobu session.

```
byobu new-session -d -s vpn;
byobu new-window -t vpn:1 -n "snx" "echo your_password | snx -s your_ip -u your_user; sleep 10"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Works like a charm!

Comment: Command `echo your_password | snx -s your_ip -u your_user; sleep 10` isn't executed at all. An empty session is created.

Answer (score 1):

The approved answer doesn't work for me. It creates an empty tmux session with no command executed inside. So this is my way to do this task:

```
byobu-tmux new-session -d "echo <password> | nohup snx -s <host> -u <user>"
```

Only one command to make it work. `nohup` is required because snx process is going to the background and returning prompt. After that, tmux exits, and snx is not assigned to the terminal. Without `nohup` after tmux exits, the system will terminate the snx process.